# Prevent users to create opportunity based on field value on Account

Tags: custom, button

We have a custom List button 'New Opportnity', that appear on opportunity related list on contact page.

**Need a new functionality** - User should be able to create an opportunity from Contact page only when a field 'Account_Reviewed' on Account object is checked(true).
Please suggest some great options.

I am thinking of following option.  Not sure how to implement it. Don;t want to go for any VF page solution.
- User cliks the 'New Opportunity' button on contact page, it will bring opportunity edit page with error message on top - 'You can't create an opportunity as Account is not Reviewed'.

Comment: My suggestion is to create custom 'New' button, that have JS code inside to query account and check field value. if everything is ok -- redirect to creation page, if not - show error.

Comment: That is simple, but bad solution. I would recommend to add some trigger that perform this check to avoid Opportunity creation during data migration or another non standard UI flow

Comment: @kurunve why is it a bad solution